# Search across multiple fields using sails.js/waterline

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, waterline

I'm venturing into the world of sails.js, using an Angular front end. In the past, I have used Angular's browser-side filtering on tables, which allows the user to search across multiple columns, using...

`<tr ng-repeat="thing in things | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchThing">`

..but I'd like to implement server-side paginations, sorting and filtering. I'm OK with the concepts behind pagination and sorting, but I'm wondering if it's possible to search across all columns in the same way that Angular allows? Or am I restricted to searching a single field at a time, and having a separate text box/dropdown for each search criteria, as I can only perform a `where` on a single field....

```
{
  "where" : {
    "username" : {
      "contains" : "da"
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think I can do it with ORs, it's actually the Waterline query language, so can do something like....

```
{
    "where": {
        "or": [{
            "username": {
                "contains": "da"
            }
        }, {
            "firstName": {
                "contains": "da"
            }
        }, {
            "lastName": {
                "contains": "da"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```